# Chain to array index?

Tags: arrays, perl, chaining

It is possible to get an element of an array from the result of a function by chaining, as follows:

```
print $elem->descendants->[0]->as_trimmed_text();
```

where `$elem` is an `HTML::Element`.

Sometimes this seems to work with some functions, but the above didn't work.  I cannot find any documentation about whether this type of chaining is meant to work.

The normal non-chaining way would be:

```
($elem->descendants)[0]->as_trimmed_text();
```

Comment: What is the type of `$elem->descendants->[0]`?  If it is a blessed object with methods you can chain it like this. If it's just a map (unblessed), then no.

Comment: It is an `HTML::Element`

Comment: Do you have the correct `HTML::Element`? There are at least two different such packages.

Comment: It's version v5.03. cpan says it's up to date.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs of the [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ecjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Element.pm) module the method [`descendants`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ecjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Element.pm#descendants) returns a list.

> **descendants**
> @descendants = $h->descendants();

> In list context, returns the list of all $h's descendant elements,
> listed in pre-order (i.e., an element appears before its content-
> elements). Text segments DO NOT appear in the list.
> In scalar context, returns a count of all such elements.

Then you have to index into the returned list with the subscript operator, like you say.

---

The arrow operator has two roles.  When its right-hand side is a `[...]` subscript, which is the case contemplated here, it accesses individual array elements via the *array reference* which has to be the thing on its left side. From [Arrow operator in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator)

> If the right side is either a [...] , {...} , or a (...) subscript, then the left side must be either a hard or symbolic reference to an array, a hash, or a subroutine respectively.

So to use it in that way we'd need an arrayref returned from `descendants`. Often functions do return an array reference, which is probably when you had it work that way.

The other use of `->` operator is when the left-hand side of it is an object (blessed reference) or a class/package name, generally to invoke methods

> Otherwise, the right side is a method name or a simple scalar variable containing either the method name or a subroutine reference, and the left side must be either an object (a blessed reference) or a class name (that is, a package name).

The next use of it in the line does call a method, `->as_trimmed_text()`, so apparently the first element of the list returned by `descendants` is an object.

Answer (score 1):

As has been explained, the indirection operator imposes scalar context on its operands and expects a *reference* as its first operand

In scalar context, `$elem->descendants` returns a simple count of the number of descendants, so the operation fails. It is only in list context that it returns a list of descendant elements

You can impose list context and produce an array reference by generating an anonymous array, like so

```
[ $elem->descendants ]->[0]->as_trimmed_text;
```

But I would prefer something like

```
my ($first_descendant) = $elem->descendants;
$first_descendant->as_trimmed_text;
```